# Convert already generated reports (.roi) to pdf

Tags: pdf, report, reporting, birt, business-intelligence

We need to convert thousands of already generated report files to pdf format. One solution is to open each report in actuate viewer and then print it using Adobe pdf, but considering the number of reports that is not a feasible solution. I researched a bit on this and found that using IDAPI we can automate this process. So if anybody has any idea on this, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a functional iServer IDAPI is the only way to go here.  You should be able to build a pretty simple client to log into the volume and traverse the virtual file system.  For each report you encounter you can execute the report with an output type of PDF and a spot to land the output on the file system.

This thread at BIRT Exchange has a lot of what you need. right down to executing a report design via IDAPI and requesting the output to be in PDF format.

http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/23491-display-a-report-in-java-appliaction-from-birt-iserver/

Do you have the IDAPI API guide?  If so just point Eclipse at the WSDL and you should be good to go.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response Mystic.
No, I don't have IDAPI guide. Can you please link me to this.

Comment: http://www.actuate.com/resources/product-documentation/#actuate11sp1docs  Look specifically at the "Using BIRT iServer Integration Technology".  If this is what you need, I would appreciate an accepted answer.  :)  Thanks!